# What is the keyboard shortcut to minimise a window to launcher in unity?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

In 10.10 that I was using before 12.04, you could use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to minimize a window to the task bar.

In 12.04 <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> maximizes and unmaximizes a window.
If you have a numeric keypad you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> to minimize to launcher.

On my netbook I don't have a numeric keypad and the normal numbers do not work with the above shortcut. How can I minimize windows with a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: ALT+F9 works for me in MATE. But I wish they added shortcut labels to the right click menu on the window title.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Launch keyboard:
[image]
Shortcuts, windows, minimize window, click at the right of the bar as indicated
[image]
It will toggle to new accelerator.  Just press <kbd>CTL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> not the numpad zero.

Do note that the numpad zero shortcut will no longer work after you do this. Shortcuts now make a distinction between numpad numbers and across the top numbers, although it isn't noted as 'numpad0' in the keyboard wizard.

Comment: I use a German keyboard and this deafult shortcut is the same, but not working.

Comment: Does not work on Ubuntu 18.10 in gnome shell: there is no "Minimize window" option.

Comment: Search for `Keyboard Shortcuts` > Hide Window : `Super+H`

Comment: There is no "minimize window" entry in keyboard shortcuts for Ubuntu 18.04, like @austin said it's called "hide window" and set to `Super+H`.

Answer (score 56):

I prefer the default bindings instead of needing customised ones:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> then pressing <kbd>N</kbd> to Minimize
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> then pressing <kbd>X</kbd> to Maximize/Un-maximize

This also happens to be the default in Microsoft Windows.

Unfortunately [it's different](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=733297) for **GNOME Shell**. There you press:

- <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> to [Maximize](https://superuser.com/questions/990648/menu-accelerators-for-gnome-3-windows)
- <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> to [Un-maximize](https://superuser.com/questions/990648/menu-accelerators-for-gnome-3-windows)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to minimize a menu

Comment: alt-space, x to maximize

Comment: There is [a bug report on gnome-shell](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=733297) (v3.14+, previously i twas handled by gtk) about this problem.  Instead we have Super+(Up/Down) to Maximize/Unmaximize.

Comment: Super+H can minimize the window on GNOME.

Comment: Super+<Number> brings up the window in the dash or minimizes it if it is already open. This is enough if you just want to minimize your currently open window.

Comment: When we do alt+space in Ubuntu 18.04 it opens the menu but the usual keys don't work (for minimizing, maximizing, moving, etc).

Comment: In GNOME 42 this takes a screenshot now. :( Need to rewire my brain to use Super+H.

Answer (score 9):

If your keyboard has 'windows' key, also known as 'Super' in Ubuntu, you can minimize, maximize, left-restore or right-restore using the key combinations:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Up arrow</kbd> = Maximize or Restore (toggles)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Down arrow</kbd> = Restore then Minimize
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Left arrow</kbd> = Restore to left
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Right arrow</kbd> = Restore to right

Answer (score 7):

If you wish to continue to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> then you can. For unity* just set to it in system settings > keyboard > shortcuts > windows  as seen in the screenshot in aking1012's answer

For gnome-shell you need to set in gsettings, either graphically in dconf-editor as in screen or thru gsettings

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings minimize "['<Alt>F9']"
```

[image]

Comment: FWIW, in gnome-shell 3.4.1 the proper gsettings keybinding is "['<Alt>F9']" (without the + sign).

Comment: This works perfectly in Ubuntu 18.10.

Comment: ...and seems the only way to achieve this in ubuntu 19... thanks