# Keyboard Shortcuts no longer working on GNOME 3.4.1

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the keyboard shortcut to minimise a window to launcher in unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123223/what-is-the-keyboard-shortcut-to-minimise-a-window-to-launcher-in-unity)

I upgraded from Ubuntu 11.10 (with Gnome 3.2 I think), to Ubuntu 12.04 with Gnome 3.4.1, and my custom shortcuts have stopped working.

Opening up the All Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts, I can see that my shortcuts are still there.

All of the shortcuts that I didn't change are working, and my shortcuts in the custom section are working (eg <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to open gedit), its just that the shortcuts I had customised before the upgrade no longer work.

Under Launchers, I had changed "Launch Terminal" to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, and under Navigation I had changed move to workspace above/below to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>.

Investigating further, it looks like the default shortcuts for these actions work (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>/ <kbd>Down</kbd> moves me up and down workspaces), so I'm guessing that there is some discrepancy between what I am seeing on the Keyboard Settings and what my computer is reading from.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doug's answer on the question linked below enabled me to change the keyboard shortcuts on gnome-shell under 12.04.  The short answer is to use dconf-editor (GUI) or gsettings (command line), rather than System Settings.

[What is the keyboard shortcut to minimise a window to launcher in unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123223/what-is-the-keyboard-shortcut-to-minimise-a-window-to-launcher-in-unity-12-04)

Comment: Specifically, under: `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings`

Answer (score 1):

As answer 1 states this seems to be a bug in 12.04.

Fix announced for 12.10, see

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/965921

Tip: The Win Key is "<Mod4>"

Answer (score 0):

If you use Gnome Classical, you need to install gconf-editor and follow the instructions from http://www.wiredrevolution.com/gnome/fix-alt-tab-task-switching-in-gnome-shell

Ubuntu is really a timewaster concerning these small annoyances.

Answer (score 0):

It is nice and easy in 12.10.

Go to **System Settings** → **Keyboard** → **Shortcuts** tab → **Map Keys** here's some screenshots to make it as easy to follow as possible:

[image]

[image: Click on this icon]

[image]

Comment: Keyboard shortcuts keeps reverting to default ones, over and over again, since upgrade to 12.10. For  instance, I like using only left hand to change workspaces, and assign Alt-{# of desktop}, instead of defult CTRL-ALT-{arrows}, which requires to use both hands and to let go the mouse. ¿Is there a way of saving the dconf entries somewhere and restore it from command line on every login?