# How to set keyboard shortcuts from a script

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, scripts

I appear to be suffering from [this bug that means my custom keyboard shortcuts are lost on reboot](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/964270). I have 8 custom shortcuts, and re-setting all 8 via the [GUI method for setting keyboard shortcuts](https://askubuntu.com/a/123226/150) is tedious.

I am using 12.10 and Unity. The keyboard shortcuts I want to customise are

- "Shift to workspace left" (right/above/below) - with shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> (h/k/j)
- "Move window one workspace to the left" (right/up/down) - with shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> (h/k/j).

(At least those are the names I see in the keyboard shortcut dialogs.)

So until the bug is fixed, I would like to be able to run a script to set all 8 after I have logged in. So what command line program and options do I need to run to set a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can achieve that effect using a script like this (only deals with switching desktop, but it can be extended changing `switch-to-workspace*` with `move-to-workspace*`):

```
#!/bin/bash
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up "['<Control><Primary><Alt>k']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down "['<Control><Primary><Alt>j']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left "['<Control><Primary><Alt>h']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right "['<Control><Primary><Alt>l']"
```

NOTE: Maybe the `<Primary>` part in shortcut is redundant. Try by yourself.

To automate the process you can also make this script run at startup, using the "Startup Applications" program.

Comment: Nice try, but the `/apps/metacity/window_keybindings/switch_to_workspace_up` doesn't seem to exist. I'm browsing around using dconf-editor to see where the shortcut might be.

Comment: @HamishDowner if you want to see it you must use gconf-editor

Comment: Turns out the gconf settings are actually all correct, but the keybindings still don't work :/ Time to go update the bug.

Comment: are you sure compiz/unity actually use gconf for these settings?

Comment: You are right. I updated the answer. In my system that worked (just replaced one shortcut).

Comment: Hi thanks for the useful answer, to quickly search a shortcut path I've found useful the command: # dconf dump / | less
(Lists everything)