# How to enable a functioning minimize button in ubuntu?

Tags: unity, gnome, nautilus, desktop-environments, filemanager

From a [random Pycharm doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-remote-interpreters-via-ssh.html#ssh)

Windows in their setup appear like so

[image]

Mine look like this:

[image]

I miss my minimize button.

How do I get a windowing theme that most resembles Windows?

I want minimize, seeing the path I am currently in, ability to navigate back (with mouse or backspace), creating shortcuts [THAT WORK from the file's directory], and so on.

I am currently using nautilus and gnome (default in 20.04)

Comment: @WilliamMartens What menu? What am I looking for?

Comment: Hi @Gulzar have you tried any of the shortcuts detailed here https://askubuntu.com/questions/123223/what-is-the-keyboard-shortcut-to-minimise-a-window-to-launcher-in-unity
The windows (super key) + H works for me.

Comment: @SwallowTail No, because I don't want a shortcut key, I want a mouse-clickable-icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The buttons you are looking for (minimize,maximize) are options in 'Gnome Tweaks'.
you can download gnome tweaks through synaptic package manager, I think            software center as well. After its installed you will find it in the utilities grouping box in your applications menu. labeled as tweaks.

Win look a like themes most likely at gnomelooks.org. headings to look through - gtk themes gtk3 gtk2 and path if your asking what I think your asking, <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, turns address buttons into address bar.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MNX7HgcWqHc&t=3475s) is an excellent resource for learning to tweak Ubuntu.

Another thing to note is, I think your on the pure gnome desktop, - on your login screen there should be a branding circle, bottom right corner, - if I'm right click the logo and click Ubuntu desktop, it has minimize button.